# ORM Mapping Error

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, coldbox

I have a set of ORM objects that work on my CF9 & 10 local workstation and one of my CF9 servers (we'll say INT & EXT ) but not the other. Everything appears to be setup correctly  but then when I call prc.app.save(), an instance of the app entity I get the following message.

```
Detail:  Either the mapping for this component is missing or the application must be restarted to generate the mapping.
Message  Mapping for component dot.path.to.model.app not found.
```

They system admin says that the two servers A & B are are setup identically.

Here is the property that is causing the problem in the model/app.cfc file.

```
component entityName="app" extends="coldbox.system.orm.hibernate.ActiveEntity" table="real_table_name"  schema="real_schema" persistent="true"{     
....
property name="applicants" 
    fieldtype="one-to-many" 
    column="app_id" 
    cfc="applicant" 
    fkcolumn="app_id" type="array" 
    singularname="applicant" 
    lazy="false" 
    cascade="save-update" 
    orderby="app_num";
```

The model/applicant.cfc looks like this

```
component entityName="applicant" extends="coldbox.system.orm.hibernate.ActiveEntity" table="real_table_name"  schema="real_schema" persistent="true"{   
property name="applicant_id" 
    fieldtype="id" 
    generator="sequence" 
    sequence="real_sequence";
property name="app_id" ormtype="integer";
property name="app_num" ormtype="integer";
```

I believe that my ORM settings are setup correctly.

```
<cfset this.ormSettings = {
        cflocation              = "model",
        logSQL                  = true,
        flushAtRequestEnd       = false,
        autoManageSession       = false,
        eventHandling           = true,
        eventHandler            = "coldbox.system.orm.hibernate.WBEventHandler"
        }>
```

This is within the ColdBox 3.5 framework.

I'm looking for any suggestions to help me trace down this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the mapping is not set up properly. Are you setting them up in CF admin or in the application.cfc?

Comment: typo? it's `cfclocation`

Comment: Thanks Henry I hadn't seen that one.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Now I feel dumb. The orderby="app_num" attribute some how got set in the app_id property. It is a column in the applicant entity not the app entity.